# Proof clarification from Laszlo Lovasz' Matching Theory, "A hypergraph is balanced iff it does not contain an unbalanced odd circuit.

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

From the book Laszlo Lovasz' Matching Theory, beginning from page 468 (of the book, not the pdf file), there is a theorem:

> **Thm 12.3.2**: A hypergraph is balanced iff does not contain an unbalanced odd circuit

Previously we have defined:

> The circuit is called unbalanced if $E_i \cap \{x_1,...,x_k\}=\{x_i,x_{i+1}\}, \forall 1 \leq i \leq k$

My questions are:

1. Is an unbalanced circuit then a *graph*-circuit, given we restrict the hypergraph to $\{x_1,...,x_k\}$? (Restriction here means we take the sub-hypergraph)?
2. In the last paragraph  of the proof there is (below), *odd* here is supposed to be *even*, no?

   > Since $G_0$ is connected .... and such a path must have *odd* length.
3. Furthermore, in the same paragraph, why exactly is P a *graph*-path? Supposing the 2 red vertices in $E$ is $v_0,v_{2k}$, and we have the path $P=\{v_0,E_0,v_1,...,v_{2k}\}$. Why are hyperedges $E_0,...,E_{2k-1}$, when restricted to $\{v_0,...,v_{2k}\}$ forms an unbalanced path? That is, why is (for example) $E_0=\{v_0,v_1,$vertices not in P$\}$? Why can't $v_2$ be in $E_0$?

Comment: About the odd/even part, ultimately I understood what he is trying to convey, however I usually count cycles/circuits by the number of edges involved, so that question may be a bit nit-picking. Or, I misunderstood the definition of the path, and thus mis-counted.

Comment: Also I am not sure about the etiquette, should I post a link to his book? (But then I will have to lead you to a pirated version or a paid version).